# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function setCurPage() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I created a block with a toolbar, but an error happened:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function setCurPage() on a non-object`

I did quite some search-queries but can’t find the solution. 
Is there someone who knows the reason?

Please see my code below:

```
class test_Promotion_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('finset' => '98'))
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_At', 'desc')
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDefaultDirection() {
        return 'asc';
    }

    public function getAvailableOrders() {
        return array('name' => 'Name', 'position' => 'Position', 'children_count' => 'Sub Category Count');
    }

    public function getSortBy() {
        return 'name';
    }

    public function getToolbarBlock() {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('testpromotion/toolbar', microtime());
        return $block;
    }

    public function getMode() {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml() {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Error sniffing:

Magento `Product_List` blocks are "pagination aware". They take URL paging parameters and apply it to the collection of products to be displayed.

That means that the error you're seeing occurs somewhere in the parent classes of your block. That method is called for collections so it means that the result of one of the selects is not an object but either an array or null.

It's more likely you're receiving an array response but you didn't initialize the collection with the response so calling the method on an array triggers this error.

### Error info:

Please specify the full error info including file and line where it occurs. This will help find the source of the error.

Also use the following line next to (before / after any operation that might change the `$collection` variable) because you may be calling `$this->setCollection(null)`.

```
var_dump(is_object($collection) ? get_class($collection) : get_type($collection));
```